# mysql foreign key cascade based on multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, cascade

Say I have the following:

```
CREATE TABLE activity_invites(
activity_id int(10),
activity_type varchar(5),
username varchar(50),
status int(1),
FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES users(username) 
      ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)TYPE=INNODB;
```

Say an event is deleted (of the events table) with event_id = '1', I'd also like any entries in this activity_invites tables with activity_id = '1' and activity_type = 'e' to be deleted

Something like

```
//somehow reference this only if activity_type = 'e'
FOREIGN KEY(activity_id) REFERENCES events(event_id) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Is my only option to create a table for each type of invite? (one table for events, posts, etc..)

Comment: What do you mean  by"delete an entry automatically"?  What should trigger this kind of deletion?

Comment: Say an event is deleted (of the events table) with event_id = '1', I'd also like any entries in this activity_invites tables with activity_id = '1' and activity_type = 'e' to be deleted

Comment: What should happen to the corresponding activity_invite when any other type of entry in events table is deleted?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: So activity_id references an event_id column in the events table, right?  Are there entries in the event table whose corresponding entries in activity_invites do not have activity_type = 'e'?  If so, what would you want to happen when you try to delete one of those records from events?

Comment: There are all different activity types, however, only events corresponds to type 'e'. So, if event_id = '1' is deleted from the events table, anything in activity_invites with activity_id = '1' and activity_type = 'e' should also be deleted.

Comment: So if event_id=2 and it has type 'p' (or whatever) and it's deleted from the event table, what should happen to its activity_invite record?  The event_id is just null'd out?

Comment: So, if on the events table, event_id of 1 was deleted, anything with activity_type of 'p' would be looked over. Only activity_type 'e' would be deleted.